# Importing NS* classes into a swift project

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying to use some existing code to plot an array. The code is older and references `NS*` classes.  How do I import these into a `swift5` project?

The project is set up as an `iOS 13` and I even mnaully imported the `UIKit.framework`:

[image]

However references to `NS*` are not resolving:

[image]

Here is the full source code to that swift file:

```
import Foundation
import Accelerate
import NDArray
import UIKit

class Plot {

    static func sineWave(n: Int = 128) -> [Float] {
        let frequency1 = 4.0
        let phase1 = 0.0
        let amplitude1 = 2.0
        let sine = (0..<n).map {
            Float(amplitude1 * sin(2.0 * .pi / Double(n) * Double($0) * frequency1 + phase1))
        }
        return sine
    }

    // this function creates a plot of an array of doubles where it scales to the provided width and the x-axis is on half height
    static func plotArray(arr: [Double], width: Double, height: Double) -> NSImage {
        if arr.isEmpty {
            return NSImage()
        }
        let xAxisHeight = height / 2
        let increment = width / Double(arr.count)
        let image = NSImage(size: NSSize(width: width, height: height))

        image.lockFocus()
        // set background color
        NSColor.whiteColor().set()

        NSRectFill(NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))

        let path = NSBezierPath()
        // line width of plot
        path.lineWidth = 5
        path.moveToPoint(NSPoint(x: 0, y: arr[0] * increment + xAxisHeight))

        var i = increment
        for value in dropFirst(sineWave) {
            path.lineToPoint(NSPoint(x: i, y: value * increment + xAxisHeight))
            i += increment
        }

        // set plot color
        NSColor.blueColor().set()
        path.stroke()

        image.unlockFocus()
        return image
    }

    var imageView = NSImageView()
    imageView.image = plotArray(sineWave, 500, 200)
}
```

Comment: These are macOS classes and functions...

Comment: OK thanks - how do we know /where is it documented which are which?

Comment: ⌃⌘-click on the symbol. This shows the header file. On the top is the framework which the symbol belongs to. In case of `NSImage` it's `AppKit` which is the macOS equivalent to `UIKit`.

Comment: @javadba Added a detailed answer...

Comment: @Macmade and i awarded within single digit seconds of having waited min amount. thx for the info

Comment: @vadian is there a way to do that `^-cmd-click` without the _click_ since I'm a keyboardist?

Comment: Yes, it is ⌃⌘J.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not about Swift.

**You are trying to use classes and functions from the Cocoa framework (macOS) on iOS.**

While both macOS and iOS use the Foundation framework, iOS uses **UIKit** while macOS uses **AppKit**.
So some adaptation is needed, as some stuff on macOS isn't available on iOS, and vice-versa.

Based on your example:

```
NSImage      -> UIImage
NSImageView  -> UIImageView
NSColor      -> UIColor
NSBezierPath -> UIBezierPath
NSRect       -> CGRect
NSPoint      -> CGPoint
NSSize       -> CGSize
```

Note that these are different classes/functions.
Functionalities are roughly the same, and everything should be fine in your example. But keep in mind this is not simply a difference in prefix.

**EDIT**

AppKit documentation is available here:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit